# The deployment of .NET Core 3.1 with Angular 8.3 for HTTPS is not functioning as expected

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have deployed a web application built in .NET Core 3.1 Web API with Angular 8.3. Initially, I deployed the same build on HTTP with a specific IP, and it worked perfectly. However, when I deployed it with HTTPS, it did not work. Both the Web API and Angular project are in a single solution.

The final result in the screenshot can be view:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by it does not work ? you should identify the problem , why it does not work , obviously if angular is unable to reach the Api will throw an error and it can be related to multiple things . did you configured your angular  and dotnet projects to use Https ?, but as i see it is related the IIS and domain configuration and not  to the project it self .

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but the issue is not getting resolved. I successfully deployed it on HTTP, but HTTPS is not working.

Comment: This image is the IIS default page, which means the https request doesn't go to your angular application. You should make sure you have set the right folder path when hosting your web application. Please post the image about how you set the folder for this 443 port inside the web application,